# Three JS Perspective Camera FOV and Near/Far

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

We have a model loaded on Three JS Fiber and we see some projects that load a similar model but their camera looks more steady and looks like the they have and standard to make it look like its bigger in front like a build.

[image]

But on our model we have the next:

[image]

We use some calculations on a Perspective Camera for the near and far updating the matrix like:

```
// Creamos la cámara
        const fov = 75;
        const near = 0.1;
        const far = 1000;
        camera.position.z = 5;
        camera.aspect = gl.domElement.clientWidth / gl.domElement.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        // Establecemos el aspect ratio de la cámara para que coincida con el del renderizador
        const updateCameraAspect = () => {
          camera.aspect = gl.domElement.clientWidth / gl.domElement.clientHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        };

        // Llamamos a la función updateCameraAspect cada vez que el tamaño del canvas cambia
        window.addEventListener("resize", updateCameraAspect);
        updateCameraAspect();
```

But as you see our camera looks to near and not as we desire as the first image.

Any advice?

Last comment update:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You’re getting some unrealistic angles because your field-of-view is pretty wide. Try something between 30-45 degrees, and it’ll look closer to a regular camera lens.

Keep in mind that a narrower FOV will require you to move the camera back a bit to fit the barn in the frame. Also, I’m not sure why you’re declaring `const fov = xx` and then you don’t use that value anywhere. Try updating the camera property directly, like:

```js
camera.fov = 40;
camera.near = 0.1;
camera.far = 100;
camera.position.z = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Marq, that make sense let me try this

Comment: As we added the change and set the parameters directly and it looks a little bit better but we feel the vertical fov still looks stretched

Comment: There are many reasons why it could look vertically stretched. Could be the canvas, or the scale of the Mesh. I'd need to see a live example to give you a definitive reason.